# Create a dynamic form from a list of attributes (Fields) in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model Category which has above 4000 Categories stored in the database. One field is called attributes which is a JSONField and its content is a list of objects that details what Fields should the Product model have. For example a Computer has [Processor Speed, RAM Size] While a Camera would have [Lens Size, Sensor Size].
The list of the attributes are more comprehensive than that. to give you an example. it looks something like this

```
[ { "name": "Processor Speed",
    "isMandatory": "1",
    "InputType": "Text" },
  { "name": "RAM Size",
    "isMandatory": "0",
    "InputType": "Integer" }]
```

the whole 4000+ Categories with each having its own set of attributes needs Forms. And i figured that i can create a form by passing the attributes as a list to the **init** function and then assign each to its name while required can be extracted as well. even the input type.

Now. is there any better way or a simpler way to accomplish this without having to modify the **init** ? by that i don't mean at the model level. I mean to create a Dynamic form without the need to modify the **init** method on the form class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django and ebay multi listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362048/django-and-ebay-multi-listing)

Comment: How is this a duplicate ? This is about generating dynamic forms. The Django ebay is about database design !!

Comment: I don't see any relation between both.. Not the question neither the answer. But thanks for your help.